# Google App Engine Java Hibernate - SQL Connection Timing Out

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Trying to connect to Google App Engine Standard to its Google SQL. Connection is timing out.

Using  SessionFactory and Hibernate, along with C3P0.

I can access the SQL database via the external IP. But when depoloying into production, the server cannot access to internal SQL instance.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired 
from the underlying database!
[Cause: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: 
A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory 
or source.
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:89)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1884)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
at com.bencowan.model.dao.DAOTest.getAllRecords(DAOTest.java:53)
at com.bencowan.rest.FilmResource.getUsers(FilmResource.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle(ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1182)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:296)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:202)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:699)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:661)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:631)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:825)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:273)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Already:
Changed Class Driver from Drive to Google Drive
Changed URL to different formats of instances

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    Properties prop = new Properties();

    prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "root");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");    
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext");
    prop.setProperty("connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size","0");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size","1");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout","300");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements","10");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period","3000");

    Configuration configObj = new Configuration();
    configObj.addProperties(prop).addAnnotatedClass(MyClass.class);

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Hibernate.cfg.xml").toString());


    if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
        configObj.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class","com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver");
        configObj.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:mysql:google://INSTANCE_HERE/filmdb");

    } else {
    configObj.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    configObj.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:mysql://XX.XXX.XX.XXX:3306/XXXX");
    }

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistryObj = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configObj.getProperties()).build(); 
    SessionFactory factoryObj = configObj.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryObj);  // Creating Hibernate Session Factory Instance  
    return factoryObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved. Seems Hibernate was the issue. Now using Standard Javax.Persistence.